# Stack overflow when parsing a lengthy query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, concat

I have a lengthy T-SQL Script.  When SQL Server attempts to parse the script, it raises this error:

```
Msg 565, Level 18, State 1, Line 106620
A stack overflow occurred in the server while compiling the query.
Please simplify the query.
```

The only thing I can see to simplify my query is to remove portions of the data I'm sending to the stored procedure.

```sql
USE MyDatabase
GO

DECLARE
    @p0 VarChar(512)
    , @p1 VarChar(50)
    , @p2 VarChar(Max)
    , @RETURN_VALUE Int

SET @p0 = 'CN=domain.all.users,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=mycompany,DC=com'
SET @p1 = 'Member'
SET @p2 = 'CN=Doe1\, John1,OU=Users,OU=Div1,DC=domain1,DC=us,DC=mycompany,DC=com'
    + CHAR(31) + 'CN=Doe2\, John2 P,OU=Users,OU=Div2,DC=domain1,DC=us,DC=mycompany,DC=com'
    + CHAR(31) + 'CN=Doe3\, John3,OU=Users,OU=Div3,DC=domain2,DC=us,DC=mycompany,DC=com'
    + CHAR(31) + 'CN=Doe4\, John4 L,OU=Users,OU=Div4,DC=domain2,DC=us,DC=mycompany,DC=com'
    + CHAR(31) + 'CN=Doe5\, Jane1 H,OU=Users,OU=Div5,DC=domain3,DC=us,DC=mycompany,DC=com'
    --- a little over 100,000 more similar lines --- 
    + CHAR(31) + 'CN=DoeN\, JohnN L,OU=Users,OU=DivN,DC=domainN,DC=us,DC=mycompany,DC=com'

PRINT @p0
PRINT @p1
PRINT LEFT(@p2, 250)

EXEC @RETURN_VALUE = 
    [dbo].[updatePersonGroupByGroup2]
    @groupDN = @p0,
    @role = @p1,
    @memberList = @p2

PRINT @RETURN_VALUE
```

The error occurs at the first line following my lengthy string concatenations.  Prior to the string concatenations, I attempted using a single, very long string, but SSMS became non-responsive when attempting to load the script from a file or when pasting the script into the editor window.

I'd try reducing the quantity of data, but the stored procedure is performing a full outer join to determine differences between the incoming data and the existing data.  The portion of the logic which determines which information on the database should be deleted will only work if all the external data is brought in.

Due to the sheer quantity of data, attempting to perform a kill-n-fill operation on the table causes the database transaction log to blow-up faster than transaction log backups can shrink it, and thus the reason for a full outer join.

**EDIT**

Replacing the 106,000 + lines of string concatenation with a temporary table and inserting the values into that table for subsequent concatenation in a much shorter query, avoids the stack overflow error.  However, SSMS is still failing and had it not crashed, I may have been able to copy and paste the error to here.

```sql
CREATE TABLE #Members (
    DistinguishedName VarChar(512)
    , PRIMARY KEY (DistinguishedName)
)

INSERT INTO #Members VALUES ('CN=Doe1\, John1,OU=Users,OU=Div1,DC=domain1,DC=us,DC=mycompany,DC=com')
INSERT INTO #Members VALUES ('CN=Doe2\, John2 P,OU=Users,OU=Div2,DC=domain1,DC=us,DC=mycompany,DC=com')
INSERT INTO #Members VALUES ('CN=Doe3\, John3,OU=Users,OU=Div3,DC=domain2,DC=us,DC=mycompany,DC=com')
INSERT INTO #Members VALUES ('CN=Doe4\, John4 L,OU=Users,OU=Div4,DC=domain2,DC=us,DC=mycompany,DC=com')
INSERT INTO #Members VALUES ('CN=Doe5\, Jane1 H,OU=Users,OU=Div5,DC=domain3,DC=us,DC=mycompany,DC=com')
    --- a little over 100,000 more similar lines --- 
INSERT INTO #Members VALUES ('CN=DoeN\, JohnN L,OU=Users,OU=DivN,DC=domainN,DC=us,DC=mycompany,DC=com')

SELECT
    @p2 = ISNULL(@p2 + CHAR(31), '') + DistinguishedName
FROM
    #Members
```

The above change avoids the stack overflow error, but I've not seen SSMS finish my script.  Even with the above change, SSMS was still inserting records into the temporary table after 10 minutes, before it finally crashed as I attempted to copy and paste one of the error messages.

Comment: Perhaps your approach could use some refinement. Could you help us understand exactly what you're doing here. It seems like the string concatenation bit could be simplified if we better understood what problem you're attempting to solve

Comment: Line 106620?! You're definitely going about this the wrong way.
Is this a one-off script?

Comment: Wait, what? Why are your transaction log backup jobs shrinking the log???

Comment: The SQL Script was ported from a LINQ-to-SQL command that was logged by our application.  We are receiving SQL Time-out exceptions when the command is run.  With such a large quantity of data, this may not be surprising, but it is taking longer than 20 minutes.

Comment: I have modified the script to place each string into a separate record of a temporary table.  This gets me around the stack overflow error.  However, the script is still failing and SSMS is often crashing.

Comment: This is a one-off script in the sense that I do not plan to run it repeated from SSMS.  However, the core aspect of the script is run frequently by our application, though usually with a much, much smaller set of data.

Comment: The whole purpose of this script is to test the stored procedure, using the same data that is timing-out, in SSMS where I can track the time and examine the query plan used by SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

With both SSMS (SQL Server 2008 R2) and Visual Studio 2010 failing when attempting to execute large T-SQL Scripts, I reviewed the application logs and noted that the application was completely stuck - so I restarted it.

After the restart, the application executed the previously failing command in approximately seven minutes.  For the time being, the problem is resolved...  Though it may recur after this evening's update processes force another obscenely large SQL Command to be issued by our application.

Also, it appears Microsoft is aware of issues when using SSMS with large scripts and has chosen not to fix the problem.

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/269566/sql-server-management-studio-cant-handle-large-files

I attempted to use Visual Studio 2010's database tools to run the script, but suffered similar issues as using SSMS.  One difference, opening the file with a very long line of text would prevent Visual Studio from connecting to the SQL Server; SSMS just becomes non-responsive.  Opening the script when broken into many lines causes both to eventually quit - no error, no message, the processes simply stop running.